# Yii2 проблемы с кодировкой имени файла

Tags: yii2

Реализовал загрузку файлов по документации Yii2 https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/input-file-upload

но если загружать файл с кирилическим названием то в имени файла на сервере получается абракадабра а в бд сохраняется нормальное имя. Как присвоить кодировку UTF8 для загружаемых файлов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше не сохранять файл на диск с тем именем, которое ему дал пользователь. Лучше сохранять оригинальное имя в базу - это позволит при скачивании подставлять его файлу с помощью заголовка Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="файл со сложным именем.doc". А на диске хранить под сгенерированным псевдонимом - это может быть идентификатор в базе или какой-то хэш.

Comment: спасибо. я не додумался=) отличная идея!